# Query tuning Optimizing

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, query-optimization, query-tuning

Below is the query. How this query can be **optimized**?

```
SELECT  representative.rep_name                 AS RNAME, 
        SUM(areawise_temp.quantity*product.ptr) AS TOTPTR, 
        SUM(areawise_temp.quantity*product.pts) AS TOTPTS 
FROM    areawise_temp, 
        product, 
        representative 
WHERE   (areawise_temp.bill_date BETWEEN '2015/04/01' AND '2015/04/30') 
AND     areawise_temp.our_cust_id <> '' 
AND     areawise_temp.our_product_id <> '' 
AND     areawise_temp.Pincode IN 
(
    SELECT  pincode_list.pincode 
    FROM    pincode_list 
    WHERE   pincode_list.pin_id IN 
    (
        SELECT  rep_area.pin_id 
        FROM    rep_area 
        WHERE   rep_id IN 
        (
            SELECT  id 
            FROM    representative
        )
    ) 
    GROUP BY pincode_list.pincode
)  
AND areawise_temp.our_product_id = product.id
```

Comment: This is actually insulting. If asking took you 3 seconds (copy/paste), no one will spend any more time than that to answer.

Comment: It's 2015 already. Time to ditch the old school comma syntax for join operations. Use the `JOIN` keyword, and relocate the join predicates from the `WHERE` clause to an `ON` clause. In this example, it would be helpful (to future readers) to include the keyword `CROSS` from the join to `representatives`, to indicate the the omission of a join predicate is intentional. Absent a `GROUP BY` clause, you are going to get an indeterminate value for `RNAME`. Before you "optimize" this, you might want to verify it's returning a "correct" result (not just by accident, but by design.)

Answer (score 0):

The coding pattern `IN ( SELECT ... )` is very poorly optimized.  Change it into `JOIN`.

For example, the innermost part can be

```
SELECT ra.pin_id
    FROM rep_area AS ra
    JOIN representative AS r  ON r.id = ra.rep_id
```

Also make sure you have the necessary indexes.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to help you.  For the above snippet, `representative` probably has `PRIMARY KEY(id)`?

Answer (score 0):

Before you "optimize" this, be sure it's returning a correct result. The cross join operation to representative looks very odd. No GROUP BY, so that "totals" from product and quantity are effectively be multiplied by the number of rows in `representative`. (It's not invalid to do that, but its an odd enough result 
that we are going to question it.)

It's 2015 already. Way past time to ditch the old-school comma syntax for join operations. Use the `JOIN` keyword. And relocate the join predicates from the `WHERE` clause to an `ON` clause.

When we omit join predicates, as an aid to future readers, we prefer to include the `CROSS` keyword as an indication to that the omission of join predicates was intentional.

Also, I would avoid using `IN (subquery)`, and use a join operation to get an equivalent result.

So, first, I'd re-write the query:

```
 SELECT r.rep_name            AS RNAME    -- not deterministic, no GROUP BY
      , SUM(t.quantity*p.ptr) AS TOTPTR
      , SUM(t.quantity*p.pts) AS TOTPTS 
   FROM areawise_temp t
   JOIN product p
     ON p.id = t.our_product_id
   JOIN ( SELECT l.pincode 
            FROM pincode_list l
            JOIN rep_area a
              ON a.pin_id = l.pin_id
            JOIN representative e
              ON e.id = a.rep_id
           GROUP BY l.pincode
        ) c
     ON c.pincode = t.pincode
  CROSS 
   JOIN representative r
  WHERE t.bill_date      BETWEEN '2015/04/01' AND '2015/04/30' 
    AND t.our_cust_id    <> ''
    AND t.our_product_id <> ''
```

This should be equivalent to the original query, and return the same result ( possibly with a different RNAME value, since that's indeterminate.)

Not be belabor a point that's already been made, but that cross join to `representative` looks very odd. I strongly suspect that the original query is *not* returning the result you actually want returned.

---

In terms of performance, the next question we have is the datatypes of `our_cust_id` and `our_product_id` columns... if those are numeric, the inequality comparison to an empty string is odd.) The datatype of `bill_date`, if that's a `DATE`, then we'd really expect the literals to have dash separators, rather than slashes. (I think MySQL will recognize the slashes just fine, but we're much more used to seeing date literals using dashes, and we know for sure that works.)

Basically, we want to know about any implicit datatype conversions that we're forcing MySQL to perform, because those may impact whether an index can be used.

The next step in "optimizing" this is to use `EXPLAIN`, to see the access plan, and to evaluate whether an index we expect to be used isn't be using, or whether the addition of a suitable index might improve performance.

### [**Optimizing queries using `EXPLAIN`** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html)